# Ue4 and visual studio unrecognized guid format

Tags: visual-studio-2015, guid, unreal-engine4

When I create a class in ue4 and open it in visual studio I get an error stating unrecognized guid format. I searched Google but it didn't help

What should I do to get rid of their error

Edit: when I reopen the studio manually I don't get this error

Comment: Maybe you can post the output text from visual studio, that would be more informative.

Comment: I get a dialog box with " unrecognized guid format" text..and that's all

Comment: Okay, so how did you "open it in visual studio"? Did you double click the asset in UE Content Browser? And what was "create a class", was it a C++ class? Added by Content Browser > Add New > New C++ Class? And what is your UE version?

Comment: Yeah....and it shows the error.. but when I restart and open vs manually, the file works just fine.

Comment: I see. I've done some google as well and it seems the problem is not specific to UE, it's like a VS problem. If directly opening VS is fine for you then I'd suggest you do so, for me I always open the sln file myself. You know you can do File > Open Visual Studio so you won't have to search through the content browser. And I'm working on a CPP project now so actually I always open the sln before opening the UE editor...ha.

Comment: I'll try to figure out the guid error and post back if I have spare time, though.